# Decimal Value Check if Zero

Tags: c#, math, puzzle

I am trying to write a division method, which accepts 2 parameters.

```
public static decimal Divide(decimal divisor, decimal dividend)
{
    return dividend / divisor;
}
```

Now, if divisor is 0, we get cannot divide by zero error, which is okay.

What I would like to do is check if the divisor is 0 and if it is, convert it to 1. Is there way to do this with out having a lot of if statements in my method? I think a lot of if()s makes clutter. I know mathematically this should not be done, but I have other functionality for this.

For example:

```
if(divisor == 0)
{
    divisor = 1;
}
return dividend / divisor;
```

Can it be done without the `if()` statement?

Comment: I guess this is your problem domain, but consider that your code is going to be returning a very different result if the divisor makes the very minor change from 0.000001 to 0.0

Comment: I prefer YOUR code, than the conditional if statements. Much easier to read!! And that's what I want

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do a conditional if statement like this. This is the same as IIF in VB.net

```
return dividend / ((divisor == 0) ? 1 : divisor);
```

Make sure you wrap your second half with () or you will get a divide error.

Comment: You don't need two set of parentheses do you? return dividend / (divisor == 0 ? 1 : divisor); should do the trick

Comment: No, I had an additional set you can do it like this as well: return dividend / (divisor == 0 ? 1 : divisor);

Comment: But you do need the () wrapping the value of the result, other wise you still get the divide by zero error

Comment: @Brian - no, you don't need the two sets, you are correct.  On the flip side though I sometimes find Jason's approach more readable.

Comment: If in doubt, add parentheses.

Answer (score 13):

By using the `?:` operator

```
return (divisor == 0) ? dividend : dividend / divisor
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a division by 1 is unnecessary and just return the divident.

Comment: This good too, but I like other one for further expanding purpose. I give +1 for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much the same as an if statement, but it is cleaner.

```
return dividend / divisor == 0 ? 1 : divisor;
```

Comment: this is not cleaner than an If statement

Comment: This will cause an error if the divisor is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own type and overload the / operator to get the desired behaviour, if you really want. Implement the implicit conversion operators to avoid casting or type converting.

I don't think it would be a good idea, however, since it would add some runtime overhead; with the only benefit that you get some code that (arguably) looks a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

you can just compare to `decimal.Zero` like `somDecimalVar == decimal.Zero`